# Apache Camel 3.4 - Various Unmarshalling Errors Using Jackson

Tags: jackson, apache-camel, unmarshalling

I have succesfully written a simple use-case to unmarshal a JSON response from the Quickbooks oAuth API to refresh tokens.

With that working, I need to go and fetch the actual data:

```
https://quickbooks.api.intuit.com/v3/company/XXXXXXXXXXXXXX/query?query=SELECT * FROM Invoice WHERE Metadata.LastUpdatedTime%3E='2020-07-01T01:00:00' ORDERBY Metadata.LastUpdatedTime, Id STARTPOSITION 1 MAXRESULTS 1000 &minorversion=47
```

The HTTP call works OK:

```
    // make the HTTP REST call, without C10y* & Camel* headers:
    .toD("https://${header." + Headers.IEP_API_HOST + "}?headerFilterStrategy=C10yHeaderFilterStrategy")
```

I can check that the JSON returned is OK:

```
.log(LoggingLevel.DEBUG, API_LOG, "JSON returned: ${body}")
```

But from here it goes pear-shaped:

```
.unmarshal().json(JsonLibrary.Jackson, Payload.class)
```

This is what happens:

1. *With* the above **log** statement a `MismatchedInputException` is raised with the message "No content to map due to end-of-input".
2. *Without* the above **log** statement a `ClassNotFoundException` is raised with the message "Payload.class".

**Re. 1.**

My understanding is that responses are cached by default so it should be possible to read the inputstream multiple times. By default the HTTP endpoint option `disableStreamCache` is set to `false`, so it's *enabled*.

The stack trace is:

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: No content to map due to end-of-input
 at [Source: (org.apache.camel.converter.stream.CachedOutputStream$WrappedInputStream); line: 1, column: 0]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException.from(MismatchedInputException.java:59) ~[jackson-databind-2.11.0.jar:2.11.0]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._initForReading(ObjectMapper.java:4624) ~[jackson-databind-2.11.0.jar:2.11.0]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readMapAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:4469) ~[jackson-databind-2.11.0.jar:2.11.0]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:3471) ~[jackson-databind-2.11.0.jar:2.11.0]
    at org.apache.camel.component.jackson.JacksonDataFormat.unmarshal(JacksonDataFormat.java:188) ~[camel-jackson-3.4.0.jar:3.4.0]
    at org.apache.camel.support.processor.UnmarshalProcessor.process(UnmarshalProcessor.java:64) ~[camel-support-3.4.0.jar:3.4.0]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.errorhandler.RedeliveryErrorHandler$RedeliveryTask.doRun(RedeliveryErrorHandler.java:702) ~[camel-base-3.4.0.jar:3.4.0]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.errorhandler.RedeliveryErrorHandler$RedeliveryTask.run(RedeliveryErrorHandler.java:616) ~[camel-base-3.4.0.jar:3.4.0]
    at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.DefaultReactiveExecutor$Worker.schedule(DefaultReactiveExecutor.java:148) ~[camel-base-3.4.0.jar:3.4.0]
    at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.DefaultReactiveExecutor.scheduleMain(DefaultReactiveExecutor.java:60) ~[camel-base-3.4.0.jar:3.4.0]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:147) ~[camel-base-3.4.0.jar:3.4.0]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:286) ~[camel-base-3.4.0.jar:3.4.0]
    at org.apache.camel.component.timer.TimerConsumer.sendTimerExchange(TimerConsumer.java:203) ~[camel-timer-3.4.0.jar:3.4.0]
    at org.apache.camel.component.timer.TimerConsumer$1.run(TimerConsumer.java:76) ~[camel-timer-3.4.0.jar:3.4.0]
    at java.base/java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Timer.java:556) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.TimerThread.run(Timer.java:506) ~[na:na]
```

**Re. 2.**

The stack trace for this is:

```
org.apache.camel.CamelExecutionException: Exception occurred during execution on the exchange: Exchange[ID-WIN-10-DM-1594724136485-0-1]
    at org.apache.camel.CamelExecutionException.wrapCamelExecutionException(CamelExecutionException.java:47) ~[camel-api-3.4.0.jar:3.4.0]
    at org.apache.camel.language.simple.SimpleExpressionBuilder$26.evaluate(SimpleExpressionBuilder.java:590) ~[camel-core-languages-3.4.0.jar:3.4.0]
    at org.apache.camel.support.ExpressionAdapter.evaluate(ExpressionAdapter.java:36) ~[camel-support-3.4.0.jar:3.4.0]
    at org.apache.camel.reifier.language.SimpleExpressionReifier$1.evaluate(SimpleExpressionReifier.java:42) ~[camel-core-engine-3.4.0.jar:3.4.0]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.SetHeaderProcessor.process(SetHeaderProcessor.java:48) ~[camel-base-3.4.0.jar:3.4.0]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.errorhandler.RedeliveryErrorHandler$RedeliveryTask.doRun(RedeliveryErrorHandler.java:702) ~[camel-base-3.4.0.jar:3.4.0]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.errorhandler.RedeliveryErrorHandler$RedeliveryTask.run(RedeliveryErrorHandler.java:616) ~[camel-base-3.4.0.jar:3.4.0]
    at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.DefaultReactiveExecutor$Worker.schedule(DefaultReactiveExecutor.java:148) ~[camel-base-3.4.0.jar:3.4.0]
    at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.DefaultReactiveExecutor.scheduleMain(DefaultReactiveExecutor.java:60) ~[camel-base-3.4.0.jar:3.4.0]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:147) ~[camel-base-3.4.0.jar:3.4.0]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:286) ~[camel-base-3.4.0.jar:3.4.0]
    at org.apache.camel.component.timer.TimerConsumer.sendTimerExchange(TimerConsumer.java:203) ~[camel-timer-3.4.0.jar:3.4.0]
    at org.apache.camel.component.timer.TimerConsumer$1.run(TimerConsumer.java:76) ~[camel-timer-3.4.0.jar:3.4.0]
    at java.base/java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Timer.java:556) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.TimerThread.run(Timer.java:506) ~[na:na]
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Payload.class
    at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.DefaultClassResolver.resolveMandatoryClass(DefaultClassResolver.java:87) ~[camel-base-3.4.0.jar:3.4.0]
    at org.apache.camel.language.simple.SimpleExpressionBuilder$26.evaluate(SimpleExpressionBuilder.java:588) ~[camel-core-languages-3.4.0.jar:3.4.0]
    ... 13 common frames omitted
```

All of this is running within an Eclipse/Maven project, so I have cleaned, refreshed, compiled, rebuilt, etc, etc, to no avail.

I have written a simple jUnit and it works absolutely fine using the JSON from the above log, saved to a file:

```
/**
 * POJO Jackson unmarshalling
 */
@Test
public void pojoUnmarshallTest() {
    ObjectMapper om = new ObjectMapper();
    try {
        Payload payload = om.readValue(getFile("qb.Payload.Invoice.json"), Payload.class);
        assertTrue(payload.toString().startsWith("c10y.model.qb.Payload"));

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        fail(e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Lastly, I'm using the latest versions of Camel & Spring Boot:

```
<properties>
    <!-- latest versions @ Jul 2020 -->
    <java.version>11</java.version>
    <camel.version>3.4.0</camel.version>    <!-- latest long term support version -->
    <maven-compiler-plugin.version>3.8.1</maven-compiler-plugin.version>
    <maven-surefire-plugin.version>3.0.0-M5</maven-surefire-plugin.version>
    <spring-boot.version>2.3.0.RELEASE</spring-boot.version>
    <run.profiles>dev</run.profiles>
</properties>
```

As ever, thanks in advance for your help!

**PS**:

The POJO classes that receive the unmarshalled JSON were generated at http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/. The POJO for the working route was hand-cranked. I mention it just in case it could make a difference (it shouldn't IMHO).

The entire route can be obtained here: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Qu0vwJaSlggH6BrIgUFMU_BZNpmMQYuh/view?usp=sharing.

I have tried the Gson library and get the same `ClassNotFoundException: Payload.class` error. This is looking like less of an unmarshalling problem and more of a classpath issue.

Having two `.log()` statements gives the following output:

```
2020-07-15 10:06:27.108 DEBUG 6720 --- [mer://startHere] c.c.r.qb.fetch.delta                     : JSON returned: {"QueryResponse":{"Invoice":[{"AllowIPNPayment":false, ...removed... ,"Balance":0}],"startPosition":1,"maxResults":1,"totalCount":1},"time":"2020-07-15T02:06:21.869-07:00"}
2020-07-15 10:06:27.108 DEBUG 6720 --- [mer://startHere] c.c.r.qb.fetch.delta                     : JSON returned:
```

Contrary to the documentation, it looks like the input stream is not, in fact, cached.

**PS2:**

Adding `.streamCaching()` to the route and `&disableStreamCache=false` to the endpoint URI didn't make any difference to the second `.log()`; it remained empty.

I also tried the following Java Config approach:

```
@Configuration
public class Config {

    @Bean
    CamelContextConfiguration contextConfiguration() {
        return new CamelContextConfiguration() {
            
            @Override
            public void beforeApplicationStart(CamelContext context) {
                System.out.println("****** beforeApplicationStart ******");
                
            }
            
            @Override
            public void afterApplicationStart(CamelContext context) {
                System.out.println("****** afterApplicationStart ******");
                context.setStreamCaching(true);
                
            }
        };
    }

}
```

I can see the sysout in the console but this didn't work either.

I downloaded `jsonschema2pojo-1.0.2` and ran it against a much bigger JSON sample with the following arguments:

```
--annotation-style JACKSON2
--big-decimals 
--date-class java.util.Date
--format-dates 
--format-date-times 
--package c10y.model.qb.jxon
--remove-old-output 
--source C:\Users\...\src\test\resources\qb.Payload.Invoice.json
--source-type JSON
--target c:\temp
--target-language JAVA
--target-version 11
```

This created the root/base POJO called `QbPayloadInvoice`, which looks like it's taken from the input file name. I updated my route:

```
.unmarshal().json(JsonLibrary.Jackson, QbPayloadInvoice.class)
```

It *still* raises the `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Payload.class`.

There's nothing in the JSON response, or in any of the other generated POJOs, called `Payload`.

At the same time, my updated jUnit works fine:

```
QbPayloadInvoice payload = om.readValue(getFile("qb.Payload.Invoice.json"), QbPayloadInvoice.class);
expected = "c10y.model.qb.jxon.QbPayloadInvoice";
assertEquals(expected, payload.toString().substring(0, expected.length()));
```

Go figure!

Comment: I’s explicit enable stream caching either on the route or on the context. can you post a link to a complete source ?

Comment: I've updated the post with the link and other comments under **PS**.

Answer (score 0):

The clue exists above where I wrote "There's nothing in the JSON response, or in any of the other generated POJOs, called `Payload`." This statement turned out to be absolutely correct.

The unmarshalling had been working all along:

```
.unmarshal().json(JsonLibrary.Jackson, QbPayloadInvoice.class)
```

It was the following line that was failing:

```
.setHeader(QB_START_POS, simple("${bodyAs(Payload.class).QueryResponse.startPosition}"))
```

This was made more obvious given that I'd changed the unmarshalling class from `Payload` to `QbPayloadInvoice`.